# Filename aux not allowed in NTFS filesystem?

Tags: filesystem, ntfs, filename

In Ubuntu version 20.04.4 LTS i cant put characters like ? or " in my filenames and write them to my external hardrive because the NTFS filesystem doesn't allow them to be in the filename.
In earlier versions of Ubuntu this was allowed.

Now I have the problem that i tried to write a simple textfile to my external usb-hardrive with the name aux

I get an error message that this is a forbidden filename but why is it forbidden? The filename only consists of the  three characters aux

Comment: To clarify, you’re asking about the rules of a file system?

Comment: FYI: Check you've applied all upgrades to your system, a Ubuntu 20.04 LTS system with all upgrades applied has reported itself as 20.04.5 since the past weekend.

Comment: See this: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file and this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31976060/10164669

Comment: Questions about the rules of a file system native to Windows may be more appropriate in a Windows question answer site.

Comment: @matigo I want to write my textfile with the filename aux on my external usb-harddrive but the system won't let me even though I don't break any rules in calling my textfile aux.

Comment: @user68186 I'm using Ubuntu and in earlier versions i could write this file on my external disc but i upgraded to 20.04.4 and now it wont let me.

Comment: I wonder if the drive has been mounted with the ntfs-3g mount option `windows_names`?

Comment: You're using a Microsoft managed file-system (*as far as it's rules*), they've said it's not a valid filename, and when upgrading to later Ubuntu software; you'll find newer Microsoft mandated rules being applied.  AUX is reserved by Microsoft to refer to a device in NTFS rules as per the doc @FedKad provided earlier.

Comment: Remove the `windows_names` mount option as @steeldriver pointed out (if you want to go to dangerous waters).

Comment: I understand now.

Answer (score 1):

`AUX` is a [reserved name](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file)on MS Windows. So use of `aux`, `AUX`, `aux.ext` etc are not allowed on Windows, and apparently the linux drivers now help you to adhere to this convention on ntfs formatted volumes.